# Analytics.js - How To Insert Current Page Dynamically as Label

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

how can I get into this line:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('form').submit(function() {
  ga('send', 'event', 'orderform-step-2', 'submitted', 'http://example.com/page1', '10');
});
</script>
```

=> the "http://example.com/page1" dynamically inserted? It's the Google Analytics Event Label Value, so for that'd be useful to track videos, different orderforms, etc.

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript">

$('form').submit(function() {

  ga('send', 'event', 'orderform-step-2', 'submitted', window.location.href, '10');

});

</script>`


That's the one that worked for me, thanks to Alper and Vikram :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer `window.location.href` over `document.URL` for the current page URL

Answer (score 1):

```
document.URL
```

gives the current url of the page

you can replace your code with this

```
ga('send', 'event', 'orderform-step-2', 'submitted', document.URL , '10');
```